# Why doesn't IntelliJ compile Lombok annotations?

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

I am trying to get set up with Lombok in an IntelliJ project. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2022 Community Edition. I didn't select any specific build system (Maven, Gradle, etc.) for my project, but I configured source, test, and output directories for IntelliJ.

IntelliJ does recognize Lombok within the editor, and will not show any errors if I use setters and getters generated by Lombok. It is only when compiling that I see any errors.

IntelliJ is able to compile normal java code fine when I run *build*, but it doesn't process Lombok annotations. Strangely, it generates `generated` and `generated_tests` directories in the output folder, which I assume are supposed to hold Java code after all annotation processing. But, those files are empty. Instead, the compiled class files (without any Lombok getters and setters) are created in their usual output folders.

In the build output, I see the warning

```
java: JPS incremental annotation processing is disabled. Compilation results on partial recompilation may be inaccurate. Use build process "jps.track.ap.dependencies" VM flag to enable/disable incremental annotation processing environment.
```

If I use the setters and getters generated by Lombok in my source code, my build instead fails with errors such as

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getName()
location: class mypackage.MyClass
```

I have followed advice from similar questions, including

- I ensured that the (builtin) Lombok plugin is enabled and installed.
- I checked `Enable annotation processing` and `Obtain processors from project classpath` in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors.
- I added the `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false` flag to the "User-local build process VM Options" setting in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler.
- I ensured that my version of Lombok is the newest one (version 1.18.24). I downloaded the jar file directly from the Project Lombok website, and included it as an external library.
- After taking all of these steps, I invalidated my cache and restarted the IDE.

Other info:

- I am using OpenJDK 18.

#### Edit 1

The following is written to `log/build.log` when I rebuild the project (without relying on setters and getters)

```
2022-06-14 22:50:45,429 [     32]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
2022-06-14 22:50:45,687 [    290]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Connection to IDE established in 234 ms
2022-06-14 22:50:45,857 [    460]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Loading model: project path = C:/Users/laxon/Desktop/Coding/Languages/Java/LombokTest, global options path = C:/Users/laxon/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/options
2022-06-14 22:50:46,037 [    640]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Model loaded in 179 ms
2022-06-14 22:50:46,037 [    640]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Project has 1 modules, 3 libraries
2022-06-14 22:50:46,111 [    714]   INFO - #c.i.u.i.FilePageCache - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=980
2022-06-14 22:50:46,557 [      5]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - ==================================================
2022-06-14 22:50:46,584 [     32]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
2022-06-14 22:50:46,852 [    300]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Connection to IDE established in 251 ms
2022-06-14 22:50:47,047 [    495]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Loading model: project path = C:/Users/laxon/Desktop/Coding/Languages/Java/LombokTest, global options path = C:/Users/laxon/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/options
2022-06-14 22:50:47,219 [    667]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Model loaded in 171 ms
2022-06-14 22:50:47,219 [    667]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Project has 1 modules, 3 libraries
2022-06-14 22:50:47,283 [    731]   INFO - #c.i.u.i.FilePageCache - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=980
2022-06-14 22:50:47,432 [    880]   INFO - #o.j.j.i.IncProjectBuilder - Building project; isRebuild:true; isMake:false parallel compilation:false
2022-06-14 22:50:47,433 [    881]   INFO - #o.j.k.j.b.KotlinBuilder - is Kotlin incremental compilation enabled for JVM: true
2022-06-14 22:50:47,433 [    881]   INFO - #o.j.k.j.b.KotlinBuilder - is Kotlin incremental compilation enabled for JS: true
2022-06-14 22:50:47,437 [    885]   INFO - #o.j.k.j.b.KotlinBuilder - is Kotlin compiler daemon enabled: true
2022-06-14 22:50:47,437 [    885]   INFO - #o.j.k.j.b.KotlinBuilder - Label in local history: build started 9039cfb8
2022-06-14 22:50:47,472 [    920]   INFO - #o.j.j.b.i.CompilerReferenceIndex - backward reference index deleted
java.lang.Exception
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.removeIndexFiles(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:190)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.removeIndexFiles(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:183)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBuilder.java:173)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:444)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:197)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:150)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:348)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:175)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:218)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2022-06-14 22:50:47,472 [    920]   INFO - #o.j.j.b.i.CompilerReferenceIndex - backward reference index version doesn't exist
2022-06-14 22:50:47,653 [   1101]   INFO - #o.j.j.i.IncProjectBuilder - Cleaned output directories in 49 ms
2022-06-14 22:50:47,887 [   1335]   INFO - #o.j.k.j.b.KotlinBuilder - KotlinTargetsIndex created in 31 ms
2022-06-14 22:50:47,900 [   1348]   INFO - #o.j.k.j.b.KotlinBuilder - Total Kotlin global compile context initialization time: 48 ms
2022-06-14 22:50:48,377 [   1825]   INFO - #o.j.j.i.j.JavaBuilder - Compiling 1 java files; module: LombokTest
2022-06-14 22:50:49,880 [   3328]   INFO - #o.j.j.i.j.JavaBuilder - Compiling 1 java files; module: LombokTest (tests)
2022-06-14 22:50:50,562 [   4010]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildSession - Build duration: Builder 'Backward references indexer' took 65 ms; 0 sources processed
2022-06-14 22:50:50,562 [   4010]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildSession - Build duration: Builder 'Java' took 1 s 913 ms; 2 sources processed (956 ms per file)
2022-06-14 22:50:50,562 [   4010]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildSession - Build duration: Builder 'Kotlin Builder' took 538 ms; 0 sources processed
2022-06-14 22:50:50,567 [   4015]   INFO - #o.j.j.i.j.JavaBuilder - javac 18.0.1.1 was used to compile [LombokTest]
2022-06-14 22:50:50,937 [      3]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - ==================================================
2022-06-14 22:50:50,963 [     29]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
2022-06-14 22:50:51,217 [    283]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Connection to IDE established in 233 ms
2022-06-14 22:50:51,238 [    304]   INFO - #c.i.o.u.i.w.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational
2022-06-14 22:50:51,262 [    328]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Loading model: project path = C:/Users/laxon/Desktop/Coding/Languages/Java/LombokTest, global options path = C:/Users/laxon/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/options
2022-06-14 22:50:51,441 [    507]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Model loaded in 177 ms
2022-06-14 22:50:51,441 [    507]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Project has 1 modules, 3 libraries
2022-06-14 22:50:51,512 [    578]   INFO - #c.i.u.i.FilePageCache - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=980
2022-06-14 22:50:51,662 [    728]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Pre-loaded process ready in 725 ms
2022-06-14 22:50:51,722 [    788]   INFO - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Build canceled, but no build session is running. Exiting.
```

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in IDE logs? Go to `Help | Show Log in ...` and check `idea.log` and `build-log/build.log` files right after performing the build action.

Comment: See if disabling Lombok plugin helps.

Comment: I added logs to the question. Disabling the Lombok marked Lombok-generated functions as errors within the editor, but otherwise didn't affect anything.

Comment: Are you sure the annotation processor class is present in classpath? Have you added the lombok dependencies to the project?

Comment: I've added the lombok.jar file to the project as a dependency (latest version), and under Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors, I have "Obtain processors from project classpath" selected. Is there some other way that I am supposed to identify lombok.jar as an annotation processor to IntelliJ?

Comment: Please [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the example project to reproduce.